# sharepoint 2013 : use variables such as $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/ for cssregistration?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

how do you use variable in the html (not master) ?

```
<!--MS:<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style%20Library/fr-fr/Themable/foo.css %>" runat="server"/>-->
```

does not work : no master is generated (Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Design.ConversionErrorMasterPage). While it works if I use the full path instead of a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the < for the Name attribute

```
<!--MS:<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="<&lt; $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style%20Library/fr-fr/Themable/foo.css %&gt;" runat="server"/>-->
```